# I-751 - what counts as detained, and a letter of good conduct?

Tags: usa, greencard, uk-citizens

On I-751, it says that if I have ever been arrested or detained I need to submit a statement that no charges were filed.

Last year, I was taken to hospital by police after an argument (I had been recently diagnosed with bipolar, it was argued that I was unstable, was found to be stable by all staff at the hospital and left after a few hours); I was never even specifically told I was detained (and police left as soon as I was in the ER area), although I imagine they would have stopped me had I tried to walk away.

Does this count as detained? Do I need to mention it?

If so, the police where I live provide a "letter of good conduct" - is this what I want? The other (and cheaper) service just states "search for record", while the I-751 instructions says that the important part is confirming no charges were filed, so I'm not sure which I should be doing here.

Comment: You were certainly detained when taken against your will by the police to an ER for evaluation, but it may not have been recorded as such officially if you were allowed to leave unaccompanied. However, it would be safer to find out whether the officers filed a report and, if so, you need to include that. A record search should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You were certainly detained when, against your will, the police took you to a emergency medical facility to be evaluated. It would have been logged by the police, they're required to make a record of all interactions, but it doesn't sound as though charges were filed against you. However, it would be advisable to request a record search so that you are clear on what you would need to include in your application.

A certificate of good conduct, or lack of criminal record, is either a local police check or an FBI records check, or both. Since the I-751 is to remove conditions on permanent resident status and, as you are expected to be open and honest in the information you provide, you may need the more costly background check.